# Print string with `%016llx`

Tags: c, gcc, printf

Sorry for the probably basic question, but I'm trying to understand some code and I can't understand what this (`%016llx`) placeholder means.

I understand that %x is HEX coding, and to the best of my knowledge the numbers in between should be the number of digits and the `0` padding; but I cannot decode the `016ll` sequence, and googling didn't helped so much more than showing an example in which it was somehow related to gcc.

Given that I'm a nearly-zero-experience programmer, can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [description of `fprintf()` in the C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1) tells us that the `%016llx` conversion specification is made up of

1. the mandatory `%` character
2. a `0` flag for padding
3. the `16` as "minimum field width"
4. the `ll` as "length modifiers"
5. the `x` conversion specifier

**So, in whole it means to write a `unsigned long long int` in hexadecimal notation occupying a minimum of 16 positions, padded with `0`.**

Answer (score 6):

The `ll` indicates that the argument will be interpreted as a `long long` `int` of the appropriate signedness. The `x` indicates hexadecimal, the `0` indicates that the output will be zero-padded, and the `16` is the width of the number to be printed.

Answer (score 3):

The `ll` (ell-ell) stands for `long long`. You are right about the rest, it means:

1. Take the `long long` numer (from the stack)
2. Format it as a hexadecimal numer on 16 places with zero-padding on left.

Comment: +1 for the spelling, as at first glance I've read 11 (one-one)